# Can I - on a Samsung phone - opena new Activity or App in pop-up view?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I have tried it out and by using

```
SMultiWindowActivity.makeMultiWindowIntent(intent, SMultiWindowActivity.ZONE_A);
```

I can make an action intent appear on the top half of the screen.

Is there a way to make the same intent appear as a pop-up window?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `float` for the scale:

```
makeMultiWindowIntent(Intent intent, float scale)
```

See the [SMultiWindowActivity](http://http://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/multiwindow/com/samsung/android/sdk/multiwindow/SMultiWindowActivity.html#makeMultiWindowIntent(android.content.Intent,%20float)) API docs.

Comment: The link is broken. Is there a new link?

Comment: The Samsung-specific way of doing this was deprecated in Android O as there is now a native API for it, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window